# Generic function to change images on mouseover

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseout

Im trying to make a generic script to change images on mouseover and mouseout.

This is what im trying, but its not working.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function mouseOverImage()
   {
      document.getElementById(this.id).src = "/templates/articulistas/images/" + this.id + ".gif";
                        }
   function mouseOutImage()
   {
      document.getElementById(this.id).src = "/templates/articulistas/images/" + this.id + "-off.gif";
   }
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="" title="Aumentar o Tamanho da Letra" class="increaseFont">
<img id="aumentar-letra" src="/templates/articulistas/images/aumentar-letra-off.gif" onmouseover="mouseOverImage(this)" onmouseout="mouseOutImage(this)" /></a>
<a href="" title="Diminuir o Tamanho da Letra" class="decreaseFont">
<img id="diminuir-letra" src="/templates/articulistas/images/diminuir-letra-off.gif" onmouseover="mouseOverImage(this)" onmouseout="mouseOutImage(this)" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should update the image source, but only if you hook it up to the appropriate `img` elements (and in the appropriate way, since you are relying upon `this`).  Given the `document.getElementById(this.id) is null` error you mention above, you are not doing this correctly.

Check the example here for one way to link the `img` element(s) with the handler functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/NdJJZ/2

Comment: ok, but how can i make this function generic? so i can use the same function to all images.. using the image id..

Comment: @LucasMatos - If you follow the pattern used in the fiddle, just replace the parts that you have that say `this.id` with `image.id` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The other answer worked too. So, wich one is the optimal answer?

Comment: @LucasMatos - Both answers solve the problem the same way, so they're essentially equivalent.  My example is mariginally more concise because it caches the original image URL instead of recomputing it in the `mouseout` handler, and Stegrex's answer makes fewer changes to your original code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check to make sure the paths are correct:

`"/templates/articulistas/images/" + this.id + ".gif";`

This looks like it might be a relative path, so you'll need to change it to `../templates/articulistas/images/" + this.id + ".gif";` assuming that's the correct relative path.

Also, you need to map out the parameter in the function correctly:

```
function mouseOverImage(object) // Accepting an object as argument.
   {
      document.getElementById(object.id).src = "/templates/articulistas/images/" + object.id + ".gif";
                        }
   function mouseOutImage(object)
   {
      document.getElementById(object.id).src = "/templates/articulistas/images/" + object.id + "-off.gif";
   }
```

Comment: i changed to the full path but its giving me the same error `TypeError: document.getElementById(this.id) is null`

Comment: @LucasMatos What's the HTML for the inline call that you're doing? Can you post the code for the <img> elements?

Comment: @LucasMatos Thanks, I've made the corresponding addition to my answer. Basically, the function definitions didn't have a parameter set up.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The other answer worked too. So, wich one is the optimal answer?

Comment: @LucasMatos I looked at aroth's answer and both our solutions are almost the same. The main thing is to remember to map your function calls with the correct parameters.